# Mafft only creating one file with Python

Tags: python, alignment

So I'm working on a project to align a sequence ID and its code. I was given a barcode file, which contains a tag for a DNA sequence, i.e. TTAGG.  There's several tags (ATTAC, ACCAT, etc.) which then get removed from the a sequence file and placed with a seq ID.
Example:

```
sequence file --> SEQ 01  TTAGGAACCCAAA
barcode file --> TTAGG
```

the output file I want will remove the barcode and use it to create a new fasta format file.
Example:
testfile.TTAGG which when opened should have

```
>SEQ01
AACCCAAA
```

There are several of these files. I want to take each one of this files that I create and run them through [`mafft`](http://mafft.cbrc.jp/alignment/software/), but when I run my script, it only concentrates on one file for `mafft`.  The files I mentioned above come out ok, but when `mafft` runs, it only runs the last file created.

Here's my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

fname = sys.argv[1]
barcodefname = sys.argv[2]

barcodefile = open(barcodefname, "r")
for barcode in barcodefile:
        barcode = barcode.strip()
        outfname = "%s.%s" % (fname, barcode)
        outf = open(outfname, "w+")
        handle = open(fname, "r")
        mafftname = outfname + ".mafft"
        for line in handle:
                newline = line.split()
                seq = newline[0]
                brc = newline[1]
                potential_barcode = brc[:len(barcode)]
                if potential_barcode == barcode:
                        outseq = brc[len(barcode):]
                        barcodeseq = ">%s\n%s\n" % (seq,outseq)
                        outf.write(barcodeseq)
        handle.close()
        outf.close()
cmd = "mafft %s > %s" % (outfname, mafftname)
os.system(cmd)
barcodefile.close()
```

I hope that was clear enough!  Please help! I've tried changing my indentations, adjusting when I close the file.  Most of the time it won't make the `.mafft` file at all, sometimes it does but doesn't put anything it, but mostly it only works on that last file created.

Example:
the beginning of the code creates files such as -

```
testfile.ATTAC
testfile.AGGAC
testfile.TTAGG
```

then when it runs `mafft` it only creates
`testfile.TTAGG.mafft`  (with the correct input)

I have tried close the `outf` file and then opening it again, in which it tells me I'm coercing it.
I've changed to the `outf` file to write only, doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why mafft only aligns the last file file is because its execution is outside the loop.

As your code stands, you create an input file name variable (outfname) in each iteration of the loop, but this variable is always overwritten in the next iteration. Therefore, when your code eventually reaches the mafft execution command, the outfname variable will contain the last file name of the loop.

To correct this, simply insert the mafft execution command inside the loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

fname = sys.argv[1]
barcodefname = sys.argv[2]

barcodefile = open(barcodefname, "r")
for barcode in barcodefile:
        barcode = barcode.strip()
        outfname = "%s.%s" % (fname, barcode)
        outf = open(outfname, "w+")
        handle = open(fname, "r")
        mafftname = outfname + ".mafft"
        for line in handle:
                newline = line.split()
                seq = newline[0]
                brc = newline[1]
                potential_barcode = brc[:len(barcode)]
                if potential_barcode == barcode:
                        outseq = brc[len(barcode):]
                        barcodeseq = ">%s\n%s\n" % (seq,outseq)
                        outf.write(barcodeseq)
        handle.close()
        outf.close()
        cmd = "mafft %s > %s" % (outfname, mafftname)
        os.system(cmd)

barcodefile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Lifesaver!